# Python - Sum Up values of dataframe by attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to coding in Python and wasn't able to solve my issue...

I have two dataframes, df1 and spend. df1 consist of 3 columns (name, group, value) and spend are the aggregated values per group...

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Name': ['Part 1','Part 2','Part 3','Part 4','Part 5','Part 6','Part 7','Part 8','Part 9','Part 10'],
        'Group': ['P1','P2','P1','P1','P2','P2','P1','P2','P1','P1'],
        'Price': [4,2,1,3,4,2,1,2,3,4]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Name', 'Group', 'Price'])

spend = df.groupby(['Group'], as_index = False).agg({'Price':'sum'})
spend
spend['Price(0.5)'] = spend['Price']*0.5
```

[Out[]:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHDyg.png)

Now I want to create a new column in df and for each group set a 'x' beside the Part as long as the sum of Parts in the group becomes > 50% (dataframe spend Price(0.5)) of the total sum.

But I struggle now how to proceed, would be thankful for any advice...

Regards

**Edit:** Thanks for the first answers but I have to explain the issue in detail...

I want to sum up Part Prices in df as long as I reach a certain percentage (50% in the upper case) of the Group volume. Beginning with the biggest amount from each group. And just for the Parts needed to exceed the 50% I want to add a x.

I want to know how many parts I have to check to have checked 50% of the total price of each group.

The outcome shall look like this...

[Result to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUAxG.png)

So in Group P1, Part 1, 10 and 4 are necessary to exceed 50% of the total value in Group P1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean but you could just do this:

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Name': ['Part 1','Part 2','Part 3','Part 4','Part 5','Part 6','Part 7','Part 8','Part 9','Part 10'],
        'Group': ['P1','P2','P1','P1','P2','P2','P1','P2','P1','P1'],
        'Price': [4,2,1,3,4,2,1,2,3,4]
        }

# create dataframe (column names are already defined in the cars dictionary)
df = pd.DataFrame(cars)

# calculate the total of each group and join it to your dataframe as 'Price_group'
df2 = df.set_index('Group').join(df.groupby('Group')['Price'].sum(), lsuffix='', rsuffix='_group')

# put an x by every part whose entire group total is greater than half of the total sum
df2['accounts_for_majority'] = (df2.Price_group > (df2.Price.sum()/2)).map({True: 'x', False: ''})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I explained the issue in detail in the edit of my post and added a pic of the result as it should look like in this case...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved by using:

```
spend['Price(0.5)'] = spend.apply(lambda row: row.Price *0.5, axis= 1)
```

this yields a spend df of:

```
    Group   Price   Price(0.5)
0   P1      16      8.0
1   P2      10      5.0
```

Comment: This is a better way to do what I did in my code, thanks for that. But wasn’t what I meant. I explained the issue in detail in the edit of my post and added a pic of the result as it should look like for this case...